# SCRIPT SQL COM ERRO

Tags: sql, oracle

Por curiosidade peguei uma matéria do meu segundo semestre de ADS e essa matéria consiste em fazer um script SQL com base em 3 tabelas: `ALUNO`, `CLASSE`, `MATRICULA`.

Fiz o script de acordo com o enunciado, porém meu script não executa, consta o seguinte erro

> ORA-00907: missing right parenthesis

Segue meu *script* abaixo:

```
Create Table Aluno(
Nr_Rgm number(8),
Nm_Nome varchar(40),
Nm_Mae varchar(40),
Dt_Nascimento date,
Id_sexo char(1),
CONSTRAINT Rgm_pk PRIMARY KEY (Nr_Rgm)
);

Create Table Classe(
Cd_Classe number(8),
Nr_AnoLetivo number(4),
Nr_Serie number(2),
Sg_Turma varchar(2),
Cd_Escola number(6),
Cd_Grau number(2),
Cd_Periodo number (2),
CONSTRAINT Classe_pk PRIMARY KEY (Cd_Classe)
);

Create Table Matricula(
Nr_Rgm number(8) ,
Dt_Matricula date,
Cd_Classe number(8),
CONSTRAINT fk_Rgm
FOREIGN KEY (Nr_Rgm)
REFERENCES Aluno(Nr_Rgm)
CONSTRAINT fk_Classe
FOREIGN KEY (Cd_Classe)
REFERENCES Aluno(Cd_Classe)
);
```

Estou usando o http://www.sqlfiddle.com para testar o script.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Olá,

No script constam dois erros:

1 - Está faltando uma vírgula entre cada declaração de constraint, na criação da tabela matrícula.

2 - Na tabela matrícula, na constraint **fk_Classe**, ele está referenciando a tabela **Aluno**, mas na verdade quem possui essa coluna é a tabela **Classe**

O script correto ficaria assim:

```
Create Table Aluno( 
Nr_Rgm number(8),
Nm_Nome varchar(40),
Nm_Mae varchar(40),
Dt_Nascimento date,
Id_sexo char(1),
CONSTRAINT Rgm_pk PRIMARY KEY (Nr_Rgm)
);

Create Table Classe(
Cd_Classe number(8),
Nr_AnoLetivo number(4),
Nr_Serie number(2),
Sg_Turma varchar(2),
Cd_Escola number(6),
Cd_Grau number(2),
Cd_Periodo number (2),
CONSTRAINT Classe_pk PRIMARY KEY (Cd_Classe)
);

Create Table Matricula(
Nr_Rgm number(8) ,
Dt_Matricula date,
Cd_Classe number(8),
CONSTRAINT fk_Rgm FOREIGN KEY (Nr_Rgm) REFERENCES Aluno(Nr_Rgm),
CONSTRAINT fk_Classe FOREIGN KEY (Cd_Classe) REFERENCES Classe(Cd_Classe)
);
```

Comment: muito obrigado, Deu certo

Comment: @WíílSantos, se resolveu o problema, marque a resposta como aceita ;)